# Oracle Statement repeating itself 9 times!! I need suggestions

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date

I got a script for oracle database that must have something wrong, the code runs okay, but the results are that, for each line of the result, are another 8 lines with the same result. Instead of showing just one line, It's showing 9

What could be wrong in the script below?

```
SELECT P.IDPESSOA AS CodigoCompanhia,
       E.NOMEEMPRESA AS NomeCompanhia,
       L.LACDEBCRE AS TipoOperacao,
       L.TRGDTINCLUSAO AS DataLancamento,
       P.PLNDATDIA AS DataContabilizacao,
       L.PLACONTA AS ContaContabil,
       C.PLANOME AS DescricaoContaContabil,
       C.PLANATUREZA AS NaturezaContaContabil,
       L.LACVALOR AS ValorContabil,
       M.MOESIGLA AS Moeda,
       L.LACHIST1||' '||L.LACHIST2||' '||L.LACHIST3||' '||L.LACHIST4||' '||L.LACHIST5 AS HistoricoLancamento,
       C.PLAGRUPO AS ClasseConta,
       L.IDUSUARIOINCLUSAO AS PreparerID,
       NVL(PE.NOME, U.NOMEUSUARIO) AS NomeCompletoFuncionario,
       CG.DESCRICAO AS CargoFuncionario,
       TO_CHAR(PC.PERNOME)||'/'||TO_CHAR(P.PEREXERCICIO) AS PeriodoContabil,
       TO_CHAR(P.PLNPLANIL)||'-'||TO_CHAR(L.LACNUMLAN)||'-'||LACDEBCRE AS NumeroDocumento,
       C.PLASUBGR3 AS ContasCompensacaoTransitorias,  
       P.PLNPLANIL, L.LACNUMLAN, P.PLNCODIGO
FROM PLANILHA P, LANCAMENTO L, EMPRESAPROP E, PLANOCONTA C, PERIODO PC,
     PARAMGLOBAL PG, MOEDA M, USUARIOSISTEMA U, PESSOA PE, FUNCIONARIO F, CARGO CG
WHERE P.PLNCODIGO = L.PLNCODIGO
  AND P.PLNDATDIA >= TO_DATE('01/01/2013','DD/MM/YYYY')
  AND P.PLNDATDIA <= TO_DATE('30/04/2013','DD/MM/YYYY')
  AND P.PEREXERCICIO = PC.PEREXERCICIO
  AND P.PERNUMERO = PC.PERNUMERO
  AND P.IDPESSOA = E.IDPESSOA
  AND P.IDPESSOA = PG.IDPESSOA
  AND PG.MOEDACORRENTE = M.MOECODIGO
  AND L.PLANO = C.PLANO
  AND L.PLACONTA = C.PLACONTA
  AND L.IDUSUARIOINCLUSAO = U.IDUSUARIO
  AND U.IDUSUARIO = PE.IDPESSOA(+)
  AND PE.IDPESSOA = F.IDPESSOA(+)
  AND F.IDCARGO = CG.IDCARGO(+)
  AND P.IDPESSOA = 1
ORDER BY P.IDPESSOA, P.PLNDATDIA, P.PLNPLANIL, L.LACNUMLAN;
```

thanks

Comment: You join over many tables. That is normal behaviour if you have multiple data for one record in another table.

Comment: Have you confirmed your joins are complete and correct? Sounds like it could be a cartesian result of some sort.

Comment: As a shortcut, make sure, PK(Primary Key) of Every table is made use of in Join. If even after that duplicates pop up, you have to identify the join condition which is missing.. Else do a `DISTINCT`

Comment: It means that you have one or more `1,*` relationship between the tables you're joining. You can identify which by observing which field of which table is duplicated.

Comment: Eleminate all joint tables one by one till result is distinct. And try to fix that join clause. Otherwise it's really hard to tell something without any information about your tables and data.

Comment: You should be starting using explicit `JOIN` syntax rather than implicit joins in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Add the primary key of every table that's referenced in the select to your list of output columns. This seems very much like a 1:n relation on one of the tables; you can identify which it is by checking which PKs are different in each set of "equal" 9 rows.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use 'group by' before 'order by' clause

Comment: Not in oracle you can't.  Not without an aggregate in the select clause.

Comment: @DanBracuk - [yes you can](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/15204/1), as long as you include *all* of the selected columns. It will act like `distinct`, but is much more painful. Particularly here since column aliases can't be used; all of the `to_char()` and concatenation has to be repeated exactly. You basically have to repeat the entire `select` part (minus all the `as <alias>` parts). Not sure why anyone would ever want to do this, but it's allowed. (And this, or `distinct`, is usually really just masking the actual issue).